# Use JS var in ruby line inside js file

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm trying to use js var inside ruby line (which all are inside a js.erb file):

my_file.js.erb:

```
var x = 3;
var credit = "<%= CreditsController.some_method(x) %>";
```

I know how to replace text in js var, but don't know how to do it before running the ruby part <%= %>

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this that way. You can't use client-side's language variables on server.

Comment: You could use Ajax to request data from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible because your file **my_file.js.erb** will be processed into **my_file.js** on the server side replacing every ruby code with their outputs it provides. Finally, your navigator will execute the javascript.

As Stefan said, you could try fetching that value by an ajax call, or trying to implement that function in the javascript, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is something like:

in your CreditsController:

```
def some_method
  @credit = 0
end
```

and in your some_method.js.erb:

```
var credit = "<%= @credit %>";
```